# Como nomear uma constraint no Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, java-ee, hibernate, jpa

Usando a classe:

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idPessoa;

    @Column(nullable=false, unique = true)
    private String nome;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPais", nullable = true)
    private Pais pais;

    public Pessoa(){}

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

No banco é gerado

```
CONSTRAINT fk_8pxwdacx0r81ra9d59m6erkri FOREIGN KEY (idpais)

CONSTRAINT uk_4tdehxj7dh8ghfc68kbwbsbll UNIQUE (nome)
```

Como nomear, invés de vir `fk_8pxwdacx0r81ra9d59m6erkri`, nomear como `Pais_Pessoa` e `uk_4tdehxj7dh8ghfc68kbwbsbll`, nomear como `unique_nome`.

Isso é possível no JPA/Hibernate? Se sim, como fazer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer isto modificando as propriedades da annotation @table.
Aqui o exemplo para o 'unique_nome':
 `@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "nome", name = "unique_nome"))`

Caso queria aplicar o mesmo exemplo para constraint que envolvam mais de uma coluna:

`@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"nome", "email"}, name = "nome_email"))`

Complementando

No caso de Foreign Key basta usar a annotation @ForeignKey:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idPais", nullable = true)
@ForeignKey(name="Pais_Pessoa")
private Pais pais;
```

Comment: Só pra finalizar(uma dúvida extra), caso eu queira atribuir um nome diferente pra cada uniqueConstraint posso fazer assim `@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"nome", "email"}, name = {"unique_nome", "unique_email"}))`? Ou tenho tenho que criar outra annotation? E como faço tambem pra colocar condicoes?

Comment: No caso você pode criar um array de uniqueConstraints, ficaria assim: `@Table(name="table",  uniqueConstraints={
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="nome," name="unique_nome", ),
   @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="email", name="unique_email")
})`

Comment: Obrigado foi muito útil

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta de @jhonnyvsilvab, pois o código está `deprecated`. Para chave estrangeira, faça:

```
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
```

...

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idPais", nullable = true, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "UK_PAIS_PESSOA"))
private Pais pais;
```

Comment: Olá @eri bem vindo ao StackOverflow, isso só responde parte da pergunta.

Comment: A resposta de @jhonnyvsilvab já é bem completa. Comentei apenas para complementá-la, visto que o modo indicado para chave estrangeira está deprecated. Não o fiz como comentário na resposta dele, pois ainda não tenho pontos para tal. Dito isso, apreciaria se revisse a avaliação do meu comentário.

Comment: Certo. A edição proposta ajudou no entendimento.